# Haskell Curl Help

Tags: haskell, curl, types, type-conversion

Ok, I'm trying to wrap my head around IO in Haskell, and I figured I'd write a short little app dealing with web pages to do it. The snippet I'm getting tripped up at is (with apologies to [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), though to be fair, I'm not trying to *parse* HTML here, just extract one or two values):

```
titleFromUrl url = do
    (_, page) <- curlGetString url [CurlTimeout 60]   
    matchRegex (mkRegexWithOpts "<title>(.*?)</title>" False True) page
```

The above should take a URL in string form, scan the page it points to with `matchRegex`, and return either `Nothing` or `Just [a]`, where `a` is the matched (possibly multi-line) string. The frustrating thing is that when I try doing

```
Prelude> (_, page) <- curlGetString url [CurlTimeout 60]
Prelude> matchRegex (mkRegexWithOpts "<title>(.*?)</title>" False True) page
```

in the interpreter, it does precisely what I want it to. When I try to load the same expression, and associated `imports` from a file, it gives me a type inference error stating that it `couldn't match expected type 'IO b' against inferred type 'Maybe [String]'`. This tells me I'm missing something small and fundamental, but I can't figure out what. I've tried explicitly casting `page` to a string, but that's just programming by superstition (and it didn't work in any case).

Any hints?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, GHCi accepts any sort of value.  You can say:

```
ghci> 4
4
ghci> print 4
4
```

But those two values (`4` and `print 4`) are clearly not equal.  The magic GHC is doing is that if what you typed evaluates to an `IO something` then it executes that action (and prints the result if `something` is not `()`).  If it doesn't, then it calls `show` on the value and prints that.  Anyway, this magic is not accessible from your program.

When you say:

```
do foo <- bar :: IO Int
   baz
```

`baz` is expected to be of type `IO something`, and it's a type error otherwise.   That would let you execute I/O and then return a pure value.  You can check that with noting that desugaring the above yields:

```
bar >>= (\foo -> baz)
```

And

```
-- (specializing to IO for simplicity)
(>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
```

Therefore

```
bar :: IO a
foo :: a
baz :: IO b
```

The way to fix it is to turn your return value into an IO value using the `return` function:

```
return :: a -> IO a  -- (again specialized to IO)
```

Your code is then:

```
titleFromUrl url = do
    (_, page) <- curlGetString url [CurlTimeout 60]   
    return $ matchRegex (mkRegexWithOpts "<title>(.*?)</title>" False True) page
```

For most of the discussion above, you can substitute any monad for `IO` (eg. `Maybe`, `[]`, ...) and it will still be true.

Comment: It works, but just as a follow up; am I understanding correctly that this basically means I can't return a regular string from a function that performs IO? that it rather needs to be `IO String` (or, as in the above case `IO (Maybe [String])`? What if I want to do something like concatenate the return value of `titleFromUrl` with another string, or print it out without the `Just [~a]` wrapping it? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm kind of new to the strong typing thing.

Comment: That's fine, you just need to bind.  If you have a value `m` of type `IO a`, then you can write `do { x <- m; stuff }`, and `x` will have type `a`, to which you can do anything you want.  The only restriction is that `stuff` has to be some sort of `IO` value, which can be a value or function call, or it can be more `<-` bindings.  So, you can do anything with the `String` inside, as long as you eventually return an `IO` something.  I suggest reading a monad tutorial. There are tons, here are two: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html or LYAH chapter 11 and 12.

Comment: [facepalm] Ok, I **think** that link helped. I was going wrong in forgetting that you can't guarantee the order of execution in a lazy, purely functional language. Your modification to the snippet just tells the compiler to force the result of `matchRegex` before using it anywhere. Am I close?

Comment: @Inaimathi, Nope.  `IO a` is the type of *data structures* which represent computations which possibly do some I/O and then result in an `a`.  `return x` is the data structure representing the computation which does no I/O and just returns `x`.  But yeah, the comments of a question about Curl isn't exactly the best place to describe monadic computation.  There are plenty of tutorials around, use them.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I've got some pretty heavy reading to do. Thanks for your help.